# SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if processing supports it

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a Spring Boot application interfacing with a rabbitmq broker which manages to startup fine but I am getting a constant start/shutdown of the message consumer regardless of there being a message on the queue. Below is a copy of my application log and client class:

> 2016-10-19 11:40:25,909 WARN  t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-106] SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.validateQueueNameLength(ChannelN.java:1232) ~[amqp-client-3.5.5.jar:na]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:884) ~[amqp-client-3.5.5.jar:na]
>       at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:61) ~[amqp-client-3.5.5.jar:na]
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor334.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:666) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy181.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:533) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:453) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1083) ~[spring-rabbit-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,909 INFO  t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-106] SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,910 DEBUG t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-106] BlockingQueueConsumer: Closing Rabbit Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,910 DEBUG t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-106] CachingConnectionFactory: Closing cached Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,911 DEBUG t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-107] DefaultListableBeanFactory: Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'macRequestQueue'
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,911 DEBUG t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-107] BlockingQueueConsumer: Starting consumer Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,912 DEBUG t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-107] CachingConnectionFactory: Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
>   2016-10-19 11:40:25,912 DEBUG t:[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-107] SimpleMessageListenerContainer: Recovering consumer in 5000 ms.

Below is a copy of my client class:

```
public class RabbitClientConfiguration extends AbstractEMCRabbitConfiguration     {

@Inject
private JacksonConfiguration jacksonConfiguration;

@Inject
private MessagingConfiguration messagingConfiguration;

//@Value("${data.core.pattern}")
//private String coreDataRoutingKey;

//@Inject
//private ClientHandler clientHandler;

@Override
public void configureRabbitTemplate(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(MAC_REQUEST_ROUTING_KEY);
}

@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(){
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(MAC_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME);
    container.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter());
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter(){
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(clientHandler(jacksonConfiguration.objectMapper(),messagingConfiguration.macMessageHandler(messagingConfiguration.messagingFactory())),jsonMessageConverter());
    //return new MessageListenerAdapter(clientHandler,"receiveMessage");
}

@Bean
ClientHandler clientHandler(ObjectMapper objectMapper, IMessageHandler macMessageHandler){
    ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
    clientHandler.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    clientHandler.setMacMessageHandler(macMessageHandler);
    return clientHandler;
}


@Bean
public AmqpAdmin rabbitAdmin() { return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.validateQueueNameLength

It means `MAC_REQUEST_QUEUE_NAME` contains `null` - it looks like the container doesn't check that when you call the setter.

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-661) to detect this condition.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I kind of overlooked that one. Thanks.